# Prolog - sum of row in matrix

Tags: matrix, prolog

An n x n matrix can be represented as a list of n lists, each with n elements, 
the matrix could actually
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
written as [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]].

I need to write a Prolog program to add all the values in each ROW. 
I am new in Prolog, please help. 
Thanks in advanced!

Below is what I had done, but it seems like not working....

```
sum(X):-
    result(X,0,0,Y),!.

result([H|T],I,J,Length):-
    rowTotal([H|T],J,Sum),
    write('Sum of Row: '),
    write(Sum),nl,
    (not(I = Length)) ->
    (NewI is I + 1,
    result([H|T],NewI,0,Length);!).

rowTotal([H|T],J,Sum):-
    rowValue(H,J,Value),
    rowTotal(T,NewSum),
    Sum is Value + NewSum.

rowTotal([],0).

rowValue([H|T],J,Value):-
    (J < 3) ->
    Value = H,
    NewJ is J+1,
    rowValue([H|T],NewJ,Value).
```

Comment: This looks a lot like homework. SO is not intended to be a cheat site.

Comment: P.S.: You'll get a warmer reception if you have a crack at the problem yourself and update your question with whatever snippet of code you've managed to come up with. Obviously, it doesn't have to be working (otherwise you wouldn't be posting the question), but it does have to show some evidence that you've had a good think about the problem.

Comment: yes, this is my homework, I need some guidance in this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need counters `I` and `J`. Simply unpack the lists as you go. Here's a solution for rowTotal:

```
rowTotal([], 0).
rowTotal([H|T], Sum) :-
    rowTotal(T, SubTotal),
    Sum is H + SubTotal.
```

The following tail-recursive solution is a little trickier to get your head around, but is more efficient:

```
rowSum(L, Sum) :-
    rowResult(L, 0, Sum).

rowResult([], Acc, Acc).
rowResult([H|T], Acc, Sum) :-
    S is H + Acc,
    rowResult(T, S, Sum).
```

Apply the same technique to implement `sum` and `result`.